NestJS magical imports - Nest can't resolve dependencies
So I was following this tutorial https://www.tomray.dev/nestjs-nextjs-trpc
and after finishing NestJS part discovered that my code not working and throwing this error while my code looked identical to the one from the tutorial.
[Nest] 94625  - 10/01/2024, 11:43:53 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TrpcRouter (?). Please make sure that the argument Function at index [0] is available in the TrpcModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is TrpcModule a valid NestJS module?
- If Function is a provider, is it part of the current TrpcModule?
- If Function is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TrpcModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Function */ ]
  })

Here's the code of that module:
import { Injectable, type INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import type { TrpcService } from './trpc.service';
import { z } from 'zod';
import * as trpcExpress from '@trpc/server/adapters/express';

@Injectable()
export class TrpcRouter {
  constructor(private readonly trpc: TrpcService) {}

  appRouter = this.trpc.router({
    hello: this.trpc.procedure
      .input(z.object({ name: z.string().optional() }))
      .query(({ input }) => {
        return `Hello ${input.name ? input.name : 'World'}!`;
      }),
  });

  async applyMiddleware(app: INestApplication) {
    app.use(
      '/trpc',
      trpcExpress.createExpressMiddleware({ router: this.appRouter }),
    );
  }
}

export type AppRouter = TrpcRouter['appRouter'];

After trying different things I discovered that thing that lead to this error is the fact that I'm importing type, not a whole module at this line
import type { TrpcService } from './trpc.service';

and after changing it to original tutorial version
import { TrpcService } from './trpc.service';

it started working properly.
But I'm using it only as type, not as value
  constructor(private readonly trpc: TrpcService) {}

So the question is - why this happens? Why it throws error when I'm only importing type and not the value? I suppose that's how NestJS works, or am I missing something in how typescript handles it?
PS: there are other questions similar to this, but none of them talking about this particular differences - type import/regular import
PPS: searching for type imports I found this issue which may be the answer to my question. Reading it now https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5421

If you still want to use import type for some reason. You can use other way define provider for container Nest's DI system.
When define provider
providers: [
  {
    provider: "TrpcSvc", // use string or symbol at here
    useClass: TrpcService
  }
]
...
import type { TrpcService } from './trpc.service';

// Inject
constructor(@Inject("TrpcSvc") private readonly trpc: TrpcService) {}

The most important is way that you import provider in module. If you use default import provider: [TrpcService], it mean you add class TrpcService to container of Nest's DI system with key and value is class TrpcService. It like this syntax
import { TrpcService } ....
...
providers: [
  {
    provider: TrpcService,
    useClass: TrpcService

  }
]

In opposite, NestJS don't support define type for key of providers. It is code NestJS define module options.
...
/**
 * Interface defining the property object that describes the module.
 *
 * @see [Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules)
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export interface ModuleMetadata {
    ...
    /**
     * Optional list of providers that will be instantiated by the Nest injector
     * and that may be shared at least across this module.
     */
    providers?: Provider[];
    ...
}
...
// For class
export interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
...
export type Provider<T = any> = Type<any> | ClassProvider<T> | ValueProvider<T> | FactoryProvider<T> | ExistingProvider<T>;


Currently, provider only accept value not type.

So yes, it's how NestJS works and it can't be fixed and should be taken into account:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5421#issuecomment-692295353

The dependency injection runs during the use of node, not of tsc. This
means that what's happening during the build phase is simply just
transpiling Typescript into JavaScript, during this time, typed
imports are checked for proper types, and then become {} just like
interfaces. This isn't something that Nest will be able to get around,
but rather something that should be taken into account during
development. If you want to use class interfaces, or injection tokens
with custom providers, that's something that can be managed, but
Nest's DI system cannot get around what Typescript does with import
type.

